# No attribute 'SMTP', error when trying to send email in Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, attributeerror

I am trying to send an email in Python:

```
import smtplib


fromaddr = '......................'  
toaddrs  = '......................'  
msg = 'Spam email Test'  

username = '.......'  
password = '.......'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)  
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)  
server.quit()
```

I understand that this is probably not the correct message format.

Anyways, I get an error:

```
C:\.....>python email.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\.....\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 47,
 in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:\.....\email.py", line 15, in
<module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong here... Anything incorrect?

NOTE: All the periods are replacements for password/email/file paths/etc.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Python already has an [`email` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html). Your script's name is `email.py`, which is preventing `smtplib` from importing the built-in `email` module.

Rename your script to something other than `email.py` and the problem will go away.

Comment: Also, remember to (re)move the pyc file.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. It wouldn't have occurred to me. I've learned something new today. Don't call scripts the same name as built-in scripts!!

Comment: It's incredible that so many people tested with email.py. :P. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib
conn = smtplib.SMTP('imap.gmail.com',587)
conn.ehlo()
conn.starttls()
conn.login('youremail@gmail.com', 'your_password')

conn.sendmail('from@gmail.com','to@gmail.com','Subject: What you like? \n\n Reply Reply Reply')
conn.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer would be way better if you added a brief explanation on what's going on here.

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.