# SMTP attribute error in python

Tags: python

**This was the code I used:** (used my gmail account)

```
    import smtplib

    content = 'hello this is a test messange from python code...'

    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

    mail.ehlo()

    mail.starttls()

    mail.login('myemail','password')

    mail.sendmail('myemail','targetemail',content)

    mail.close()
```

**This was the error message:**

```
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

Comment: I am new to this concept can anyone please explain in detail...

Comment: Would your filename happen to be email.py?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No attribute 'SMTP', error when trying to send email in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512256/no-attribute-smtp-error-when-trying-to-send-email-in-python)

Comment: @RafaelCardoso That is why I asked if that was his filename, if so then it is a duplicate

Comment: Thank you guys.....just resolved the problem, yes you were right my file name was email.py, now when I changed the name it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but it appears that you didn't assign the attribute. I'm new to programming so correct me if I'm wrong. But I think that is why you got the error. You're asking for an attribute to be called that you didn't define.

Comment: Hi @ Marcus Jones, can you please write the block of code that I was missing.